# Exportar datagridview a word

Tags: c#

Buenas tengo este inconveniente en exportar un data gridview a word [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de la invocación del estilo mediante comillas, deberías de usar los enumeradores, que mantienen el estandar entre idiomas y versiones.

```
        oDoc.Application
            .Selection
            .Tables[1]
            .set_Style(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleTableLightShadingAccent1);
```

Te dejo el [listado de los múltiples estilos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835210.aspx)

Saludos

Comment: Hola tengo que insertar alguna libreria para utilizar el WdBuiltinStyle? porque me sale un error

Comment: Ed muchas gracias, me servio mucho lo que me pasaste

Comment: Creo según recuerdo en tu sección de using la invocas así... using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; y ya de ahí en el código le antepones el Word.WdBuiltinStyle...